# How to get user data with discord API

Tags: python, discord

I want to credit myself using my discord tag in a script, but if for example my name changes, I want it to change on the script as well. The normal way to do this would be to connect my script to a pastebin or something that contains my name, but I have to manually change it every time so its no fun.

I've dug through the discord API docs and here is as far as i've gotten:

```
print(loads(urlopen(Request("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/513837216741720094", headers=header)).read().decode()))
```

Most of that line was suggested by a friend, but either way i keep getting a 401 error saying im unauthorized. Visiting the site manually also gives the 401 error.

Comment: also in advance, im aware that i could be using api version v9 and instead use discord.com but the line of code should still work

Answer (score 0):

You need to request that URL with a header named "Authorization" with your Discord token.

Example:

```py
print(loads(urlopen(Request("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/513837216741720094", headers={"Authorization": "Your Discord Token"})).read().decode()))
```

Discord documentation: https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).